# odoo button definition not working before setting value to a mandatory field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have a button say 'calc_val' when I click on the button I had to pass values to a mandatory field.But my button definition is not working while the mandatory field is empty.Only if I put some values to the mandatory field and after when I click on the button , the button works.The whole thing is in a 'wizard'
Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because in odoo after clicking on any button create or write function called before executing the working function of your button and for create and write you have to fill mandatory fields thats why you have to fill mandatory fields before executing any button functionality.

Comment: So what's the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hello, vbt**

You have to set some default value in that specific field.
After set default value, you can use that button behavior.
And if you want to change that value, they can change also.

May Help this answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that is a wrong method to do it.Because there is a chance that the customer won't click on the button to change it's default value.

Comment: You can invisible the button if that mandatory field value is empty.
Means, when that mandatory field value is available then and then your button is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by removing the mandatory field and then adding a validation while clicking on the final button in the wizard (For not keeping the mandatory field empty).
If any other answers are available,feel free to post.Thanks

Comment: Hi, try this
-add a state to the record,(draft, final).
 Make the field mandatory in final state only. and change state from draft to final in your button click.